# first row where value in one column higher than in another column R

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data table:

```
df <- data.table(Points = 1:5, A = c(2,4,6,8,10), B = c(1,3,4,5,9))
df <- 
Points  A B
  1     2 1
  2     4 3
  3     6 4
  4     8 5
  5    10 9
```

I want the value of column Points corresponding to the first value in column B that is higher than the current value of column A.

Expected output if A == 4:

4   (the first value in B bigger than 4 has a corresponding value of Points equal to 4)

Comment: None of hte values in B are greater than A

Comment: Your description is not clear.  Do you need `df[, B[which(shift(B > shift(A)))]]` comparison with lag

Comment: no, not shift. Given a value of A, which represents a characteristic of a person, I need to find the first value in B that has a higher value than the value in A and the corresponding Points. Is it clearer?

Comment: So you are not comparing elementwise

Comment: no, not element wise.

Comment: Is it something like `lapply(df$A, function(x) df$B > x)`, but still that doesn't give the expected

Comment: in the simple example I provided, indeed, it works, but I need to try it on the more complex. It seems too simple not to have thought of it.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```r
df[, Points[apply(outer(A, B, `<`), 1, function(z) which(z)[1])]]
# [1]  2  4  5  5 NA
```

The trick is that `outer` is producing a 5x5 matrix, where the column of the first `TRUE` on a row is the index. I tried `which.max`, but in the 5th row here, nothing is found, so `which.max(rep(F,5))` returns 1, which is obviously not right ... as opposed to `which(rep(F,5))[1]` which returns `NA` (more meaningful here).